# Can i create two windows by clicking buttons in a wxpython program?

Tags: wxpython

I have tried to do this but this is not helping.It says MainFrame has no attribute onButton1.Why it's saying that??How can I solve that?

Besides,I don't understand the use of sizer in wxpython.What's the basics of using sizer?

It'll help me a lot if I get the answers however shortly or briefly.

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame): 
   def __init__(self): 
       wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.NewId(), "Main") 
       self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)


       self.button = wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Open a window")
       self.button1 = wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Open another window")
       self.sizer.Add(self.button, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
       self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
       self.sizer.Add(self.button1, proportion=2, border=4, flag=wx.ALL)
       self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

       self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton,self.button)
       self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton1, self.button1)

       self.Layout()

   def onButton(self, evt):
       frame = NewFrame2(self)
       frame.Show(True)
       frame.MakeModal(True)

class NewFrame2(wx.Frame): 
   def __init__(self, parent): 
       wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.NewId(), "Child") 
       panel=wx.Panel(self)

   def onButton1(self, evt):
       frame = NewFrame(self)
       frame.Show(True)
       frame.MakeModal(True)


class NewFrame(wx.Frame): 
   def __init__(self, parent): 
       wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.NewId(), "Window")
       panel=wx.Panel(self)


class MyApp(wx.App):
   def OnInit(self):
       frame = MainFrame()
       frame.Show(True)
       self.SetTopWindow(frame)
       return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The wiki has some good info on sizers - http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingSizers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `onButton1` inside the `MainFrame` class like you did with your `onButton` method. Since it is defined in `NewFrame2`, the method is outside of scope and cannot be bound to from within the `MainFrame` class.